# How to change a limit vairable

Tags: real-analysis

How to show $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=\lim_{g(x)\rightarrow 0} f(x)$ if we are given that $g(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow 0.$ Is this even true?

Comment: There is something missing on the RHS? Also, what exactly does the notation $\lim\limits_{g(x)\to 0}f(x)$ mean?  For example, how should we interpret $\lim\limits_{\sqrt{x}\to 0}\sin(x)$?  If $f$ is composed with $g$, then this could make some sense.

Comment: Sorry, it should also be $f(x)$

Comment: I'm confused on the RHS. What are you taking the limit *of*?

Comment: So sorry. I just fixed it.

Comment: The fact that $\lim_{x\to0}g(x)=0$ does not mean that $g$ cannot approach $0$ for another value of $x$. For example, consider $f(x)=x,\ g(x)=\sin x$.

Comment: You still haven't answered the question: what exactly does notation $\lim\limits_{g(x)\to 0}f(x)$ mean?